# How to remove element from vector by value but only single instance of that value?

Tags: c++, vector

Here is the problem,

I have a vector and I need to remove 2 elements from the vector, one after another. I know the value of those two elements and index of those elements.

First I tried to remove those two elements using index i.e.

```
v.erase(v.begin()+index1);
v.erase(v.begin()+index2);
```

But problem is after erasing first element index of second element in the array changes.

So, I tried to remove them by value i.e.

```
v.erase(remove(v.begin(),v.end(),value),v.end());
```

But this remove all the instances of that value (e.g. if there are 2 "1" it will remove both of them), while I want only one element to be removed.

How to solve it ?

Comment: Try removing the element with a higher index first.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You may use:

```
v.erase(v.begin() + std::max(index1, index2));
v.erase(v.begin() + std::min(index1, index2));
```

or even

```
auto indexes = std::minmax(index1, index2);
v.erase(v.begin() + indexes.second);
v.erase(v.begin() + indexes.first);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you remove an element from a `std::vector<>`, any iterator at or after the point of erase is invalidated.

This is why you must first remove the element that is at a position with the greater index.

**Example :**

```
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
  vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

  size_t index1 = 3; // We want to remove 4
  size_t index2 = 5; // We want to remove 6

  v.erase(begin(v) + index2); // We remove the element with the greater index first
  v.erase(begin(v) + index1); // fine, v.begin() + index1 is BEFORE the previous point of erasure

  for(auto val : v)
    cout << val << " ";

  return 0;
}
```

---

**Edit :**

- Here is a generic algorithm, `remove_at_indexes`, for removing elements from a container by specifying indexes in form of a range (of `std::size_t`)
- It will work on any STL compliant container (`vector`, `string`, `deque` ...)

**Code:**

```
template<class Iterator, class IteratorId>
Iterator remove_at_indexes(Iterator first, Iterator last, IteratorId indexes_begin, IteratorId indexes_end)
{
    std::sort(indexes_begin, indexes_end, std::less<size_t>());

    std::size_t count { 0 };

    if (first != last)
        for(auto i = first; i != last; i++)
            if(indexes_begin == indexes_end)
               first++;
            else
            {
                if (count != *indexes_begin)
                    *first++ = std::move(*i);
                else
                    indexes_begin++;
                count++;
            }

    return first;
}
```

**Usage example :**

```
  vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
  vector<size_t> indexes { 4, 1, 9 };

  v.erase(remove_at_indexes(v.begin(), v.end(), indexes.begin(), indexes.end()), v.end());
```

**Output :**

> 1 3 4 6 7 8 9

[Demo here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/56c90c0e953bb15d).